# Fire and forget with Schedule

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to schdule execution of tasks that I don't care about whenand how they complete. It is Python3.5 and there are no other async packages enither installed or wanted to be, just "asyncio".

There is nice package "schedule" that does scheduling nicely:

```
import schedule

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(call_my_remote_url)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

There is a fire and forget code that does the job on it's one:

```
def fire_and_forget(task, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if callable(task):
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, task, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Task must be a callable')
```

However, when I put it together:

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime
import asyncio


def call_my_remote_url():
    # Do stuff, completion of which I don't care. For example
    print("started @ "+str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
    time.sleep(5)
    print("completed @ " + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))


def fire_and_forget(task, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if callable(task):
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, task, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Task must be a callable')


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(fire_and_forget(call_my_remote_url))

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

It FAILS miserably:

```
(env) $ python3 example_fire_and_forget_with_scheduler.py 
started @ 12:19:04.901547
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_fire_and_forget_with_scheduler.py", line 21, in <module>
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(fire_and_forget(call_my_remote_url))
  File "/Users/user/Projects/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 352, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
completed @ 12:19:09.906020
(env)$
```

Seems like "shedule" module is not happy, btu I don't understand why and how to fix it. Any ideas or **simple** alternatives?
*(please note, it is not just async, but fire and forget on schedule is a must)*

Comment: Have you tried just calling `fire_and_forget(call_my_remote_url())`, without any kind of scheduling?

Comment: yes. it does not work either:
  **File "example_fire_and_forget_with_scheduler.py", line 21, in <module>
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(fire_and_forget(call_my_remote_url()))
  File "example_fire_and_forget_with_scheduler.py", line 19, in fire_and_forget
    raise TypeError('Task must be a callable')
TypeError: Task must be a callable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the arguments to `do` in a way that it doesn't like. Simplifying the problem slightly, the following seems to work:

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime


def call_my_remote_url():
    # Do stuff, completion of which I don't care. For example
    print("started @ "+str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
    time.sleep(5)
    print("completed @ " + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))


def fire_and_forget(task, *args, **kwargs):
    if callable(task):
        return task()
    else:
        raise TypeError('Task must be a callable')


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(fire_and_forget, call_my_remote_url)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

So the parameters of `fire_and_forget` are passed to `do`. I can't seem to find this detailed in the documentation, but it's hinted at by [this example](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#clear-job-by-tag).